# Define additional shortcut keys without overwriting existing shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, multimedia, media-buttons

My laptop keyboard does not have media shortcut keys (e.g. "Next Track", etc).  I frequently use the laptop connected to an external keyboard, which does.  I go to Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts tab, and select "Sound and Media", and I see that "Next Track" is bound to the shortcut key "audio next".  I see that I can replace this with a custom key binding, but it overwrites the "audio next" shortcut.

I'd like a solution that allows me to map a second shortcut to this command without overwriting it.  I see that I can define custom keys, so I could make a unique mapping for `rhythmbox-client --next`, etc, but that would be a solution specific to rhythmbox.  I'm looking for a more native Ubuntu solution that will work in any player the same way the current "audio next" media keys do on my external keyboard.  Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem by following the steps in my answer?

Comment: Yup! I think the bounty didn't go through first time I clicked on it, thanks for following up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate keyboard events I suggest you the great tool [xdotool [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).

**1. Install `xdotool`** via terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

or use  the [Software Center [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).

**2. Create a script** that uses xdotool to emulate the "audio next" event from multimedia keyboards. In the terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin  
gedit ~/bin/audionext
```

Copy the following content into the editor window that opened up. After copying the code save, then close it:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 0.3  
exec /usr/bin/xdotool key XF86AudioNext  
EOF
```

Now make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/audionext
```

**3. Log out** and log in to reload your [PATH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

**4. Create the custom shortcut**

Go to `System Settings`, then go to `Keyboard`, then `Shortcuts`.

Press the `+` button at the bottom of the dialog. Provide a name for the shortcut you're about to create and for the command fill in: `audionext`. Press `OK`.

Next to your new shortcut you will see `disabled`. Click on that text and then press the keyboard combination you want to be assigned to your media keyboard emulation.

You should now be able to "audio next" with your keyboard shortcut!